# $S_{*}=X_0+S_{**}$ Inhomogeneous equation solution ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a non-zero vector in n-space. Let $P$ be a point in $n$-space. What is the dimension of the set of solutions of the equation $X.A=P.A$? ***Linear Algebra by Lang***
>
> SOLUTION. Let $S_{*}$ be the set of solutions of $X.A=P.A$(*) and let $S_{**}$ be the set of solutions of $X.A=0$(**). By exercise 7 we know that if we have a solution $X_0$, then $S_{*}=X_0+S_{**}$. Since $X=P$ solves (*) and the dimension of $S_{**}$ is $n-1$, we see that $\dim S_{*}=n-1$. ***Solutions Manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra, by Rami Shakarchi***

Since I am self-studying I acquired the last book in the hope of solving all the exercises.

**Questions**:

Why is the dimension of $S_{**}=n-1$?

Is $S_{**}$ 0? Is $S_{*}=X_0+S_{**}$ because $S_{**}$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the linear map $X \mapsto X⋅A$. We have that $S_{**} = Ker(L)$, so $dim(S_{**}) = n - dim(Im(L)) = n - 1$ since $Im(L)$ is 1-dimensional.

Since $S_{**}$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional, it is $\{0\}$ if and only if $n = 1$.

$S_* = X_0 + S_{**}$ becuase $L$ is linear. Try to prove the inclusions separately.

Comment: $L(X_0+S_{**})=AX_0=P.A$, however if P has dimension $n$, and $X=P$ to solve the equation. Why does not $\dim S_{*}=n+n+1=2n+1$? Is the dimension of $P$, really n? I could be less?

Comment: $P$ is a point. How can it have a dimension? And $S_*$ also have no dimension since it is not a vector space unless $P = 0$. We may only put $dim(S_*) = dim(S_**)$ by definition.

Comment: I was thinking of P as the solutions space.

Comment: $P$ is a point, $S_*$ and $S_{**}$ are the solution spaces.

Comment: So it means there is a solution besides P, which for me looks weird.

Comment: Of course there is. And it is nothing weird. $(1, 1) ⋅ (1, -1) = 0 = (0, 0) ⋅ (1, -1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. You have been very attentive and helpful.